# Asynchronously execute Javascript through a web driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

My goal is to systematically collect information about **every** element present on a web page. Specifically, I would like to perform `el.getBoundingClientRect()` and `window.getComputedStyle(el)` for each element.

I have been using Selenium WebDriver for NodeJS to load the pages and manage the browser interaction. To simplify, let's just focus on `getComputedStyle`:

```
    driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*"))
        .then(elements => {
            var elementsLeft = elements.length;
            console.log('Entering async map');
            async.map(elements, el => {
                driver.executeScript("return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0]).cssText",el)
                    .then((styles: any) => {
                        //stuff would be done here with the styles
                        console.log(elements.indexOf(el));
                    });
            });
    });
```

This code will loop through all the elements and retrieve their styles, but it is **very slow**. It may take a few minutes to complete for a page. I would like the driver to execute the scripts asynchronously, but this does not appear possible because each Selenium driver has a 'ControlFlow' that ensures each command to the driver is only started after the last has completed. I need to find a workaround for this so I can execute javascript asynchronously on the page (and make my data gathering faster).

Note: I have also tried Selenium's executeAsyncScript, which turns out to be just a wrapper around executeScript and will still block until it is finished. Here is my code using executeAsyncScript - it performs just as well as the previous code:

```
    driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*"))
        .then(elements => {
            var elementsLeft = elements.length;
            async.map(elements, el => {
                driver.executeAsyncScript( 
                    function(el: any) {
                        var cb = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
                        cb(window.getComputedStyle(el).cssText);
                    }, el)
                    .then((styles: any) => {
                        //stuff would be done here with the styles
                        console.log(elements.indexOf(el));
                    });
            });
    });
```

I am looking for a way to either bypass Selenium's ControlFlow in order to execute my javascript asynchronously, find a way to extract the objects and not be bound by the driver, or to find an alternative tool/solution for getting the data that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `executeScript` can take in `WebElement`s, did you see if it is faster to do all the work in one call rather than repeatedly calling `executeScript`?

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*"))
    .then(elements => {
        driver.executeScript("return arguments[0].map(function(el) {return [el, window.getComputedStyle(el).cssText];})", elements)
            .then((styles: any) => {
                //stuff would be done here with the styles
                console.log(styles);
            });
    });
});
```

If that is too slow, did you consider locating all the elements inside the script instead of passing them in?

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*"))
    .then(elements => {
        driver.executeScript("return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('*'))" +
                ".map(function(el) {return [el, window.getComputedStyle(el).cssText];})", elements)
            .then((styles: any) => {
                //stuff would be done here with the styles
                console.log(styles);
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: YES! Thank you! I don't know why I didn't think of that, but that's perfect. I tried the first code block and it works like a charm. Might try the second one too if performance is ever an issue down the line. This was my first stackoverflow question and after trying to figure this out for several nights, I finally decided to sign up and ask... Thank you for the optimal experience! :)